# PySpark: Create a column containing the minimum divided by maximum of each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark

I am working out some PySpark exercises and trying to write efficient and best practice code to be ready to work in a production environment.

I could use some feedback with respect to:

1. Is the code structured well?
2. Is the code efficient?
3. Any other best practices I missed but should make habits of.

```
import findspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

findspark.init()

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Sample Data

data = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]

# Create DataFrame

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col1", "col2", "col3"])

df.show()

import math

def smallest_column(smallest, col):
    return F.when(smallest <= col, smallest).otherwise(col)
 
def biggest_column(biggest, col):
    return F.when(biggest >= col, biggest).otherwise(col)       
        

df_small_big = (
    df
    .withColumn("smallest", F.col(df.columns[0]))
    .withColumn("biggest", F.col(df.columns[0]))
)

for c in df.columns:
    df_small_big = (
        df_small_big
        .withColumn("smallest", smallest_column(F.col("smallest"), F.col(c)))
        .withColumn("biggest", biggest_column(F.col("biggest"), F.col(c)))
    )


df_small_big = df_small_big.withColumn("min_by_max", F.col("smallest")/F.col("biggest"))

df_small_big.select(*df.columns, "min_by_max").show()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+----+----+----+------------------+
|col1|col2|col3|        min_by_max|
+----+----+----+------------------+
|   1|   2|   3|0.3333333333333333|
|   4|   5|   6|0.6666666666666666|
|   7|   8|   9|0.7777777777777778|
|  10|  11|  12|0.8333333333333334|
+----+----+----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, the code layout is good, and you chose meaningful names for variables and functions.

When I run [pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html), it complains about these unused imports:

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import math
```

It's usually a good idea to remove code that isn't used.

`pylint` also identifies "Trailing whitespace".  It is a good idea to remove that as well.

It would be good to add comments at the top to describe what the code does.

I recommend moving the functions to the top, after the import statements.  Having them in the middle of the code interrupts the natural flow of the code (from a human readability standpoint).

```
'''
PySpark: Create a column containing the minimum divided by maximum of each row
'''

import findspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def smallest_column(smallest, col):
    return F.when(smallest <= col, smallest).otherwise(col)

def biggest_column(biggest, col):
    return F.when(biggest >= col, biggest).otherwise(col)

findspark.init()

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Sample Data
data = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col1", "col2", "col3"])

df.show()

df_small_big = (
    df
    .withColumn("smallest", F.col(df.columns[0]))
    .withColumn("biggest", F.col(df.columns[0]))
)

for c in df.columns:
    df_small_big = (
        df_small_big
        .withColumn("smallest", smallest_column(F.col("smallest"), F.col(c)))
        .withColumn("biggest", biggest_column(F.col("biggest"), F.col(c)))
    )

df_small_big = df_small_big.withColumn("min_by_max", F.col("smallest")/F.col("biggest"))

df_small_big.select(*df.columns, "min_by_max").show()
```